# SQL class OVER register

Tags: sql

everyone I have a SQL question:

Table: Registration（StudentId,CourseID,StudentName）
       Course（ID,Capacity,Name)

one student could register one or multiple courses.

Need to find course that over-registed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 select c.ID,c.Name, COUNT(r.StudentId)
    from Registration r inner join course c
    on r.CourseID = c.ID
    group by c.ID,c.Name
    having COUNT(r.StudentId) > (select Capacity from Course
                                    where ID = c.ID)
```